# Watch if a process is active

Tags: process, creation

I want to create a program that, when opened "auto-spawns" let's say, another process, but an independent process that constantly checks if my program is opened or closed, if closed then i want to delete the file for example and also kill and delete the process watcher.
I also searched on google on how to create another process from a process, but to work independently, and couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: On which operating system? On Linux it's simply calling `fork()`.

Comment: Only on windows.